# Pandas - Get values within parentheses of a panda dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, parentheses

My `df` has 2 columns:

```
Name    Attr
a(bc)
b(aca)
(cba)
```

I would like the column `Attr` to have the values within parentheses of column `Name`

```
Name    Attr
a(bc)   bc
b(aca)  aca
(cba)   cba
```

I tried:

```
df['Attr'] = re.findall('\(.*?\)',df['Name'].astype('str'))
```

> `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Attr'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r"\(([A-Za-z]+)\)", expand=False)
print (df)
     Name Attr
0   a(bc)   bc
1  b(aca)  aca
2   (cba)  cba
```

Or add `()` to your `regex`:

```
df['Attr'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)", expand=False)
print (df)
     Name Attr
0   a(bc)   bc
1  b(aca)  aca
2   (cba)  cba
```