# Date extraction from text in parenthesis at the end of each sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the content in the last parenthesis at the end of each of the following rows:

```
      Text

    "«A mio avviso, e credo non solo mio, (17-11-2020 12:42:05)"
     "Roma, 17 nov – Dalle elezioni, non è facile (…)\n (17-11-2020 12:42:04)"
     'Decine di avvocati del libero foro di tutte le regioni  ... (17-11-2020 12:41:08)'
     "Ci sono riusciti: vi stanno facendo odiare l'un l'altro (17-11-2020 12:41:01)"
     'Luciano ,\xa0 coreografo, esprime la sua opinione e il mondo de... (17-11-2020 12:40:01)'
```

I followed the answers here: [Pandas - Get values within parentheses of a panda dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920443/pandas-get-values-within-parentheses-of-a-panda-dataframe-column), and tried with:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"\(([A-Za-z]+)\)", expand=False)
```

but I did not get any value, only NaN.
My expected output should be:

```
    Datetime
    17-11-2020 12:42:05
    17-11-2020 12:42:04
    17-11-2020 12:41:08
    17-11-2020 12:41:01
    17-11-2020 12:40:01
```

Could you tell me how I need to change my code to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please extract the characters between `()` at the `end of line`

```
df['Datetime']=df.Text.str.extract('(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\)$)')
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't think on matching `)` as the last character of the string. It makes a lot easier. Also, `'\((.+)\)$'` would works. I admire your solutions!

Comment: Thanks wwnde! I did not think of that as possible solution.